# Change default value of variable within Bash script from command line

Tags: bash, shell

I have a Bash script that has a variable with a default value, defined at the start of the script:

```
foo="default"
```

The script also accepts a command line option to override the value of that variable for the execution.

```
./myscript -foo "new val"
```

No problems there. But what I was wondering is if there's a way to persist the value passed in through the command line to further executions later in time.

To clarify:

```
foo="default"
echo $foo
```

**Execution 1:**

```
$: ./myscript
```

default

**Execution 2:**

```
$: ./myscript -foo "new value"
```

new value

**Execution 3:**

```
$: ./myscript
```

new value

I'm assuming the answer is no, but I just thought I'd check with those who may be more familiar with Bash or scripting in general. If it's possible, I'd like to avoid storing the value in a file, though I'm not opposed to the idea if there's a folder that's generally used for such things that isn't the user's home directory.

Comment: You can write the value out to a configuration file that you read in the script.

Comment: I was thinking of a really dirty hack which includes that the script modifies itself. But if at all, this only works under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE:

#### bar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
: ${FOO='default'}
sed -Ri "s/(?<=FOO=')[a-z]+/$FOO/" bar.sh
```

Depending on valid values for your variable `FOO`, you have to change the regex in `sed`.

I did this with super-sed which provides `-R` for extended regex patterns. In this case for the look-behind.

Answer (score 0):

The standard idiom is

```
: ${FOO:=default}
```

If `FOO` has a non-empty value, it is not changed; otherwise it is set to the given default. To preserve an existing empty value, use

```
: ${FOO=default}
```

To invoke the script with a non-default value, use

```
FOO=custom ./myscript
```

to provide a value for `FOO` in the environment of `myscript`. Or, if your `-foo` option assigns a value to `FOO`, just make sure to put the `: ${FOO=default}` line *after* that code.

Comment: Can you explain how this persists the state of `FOO` between two runs of the script because I do not get it.

Comment: Oh, I missed that condition. There's no way to do that without storing the value in a file. Variables are local to the memory space of the process that sets them.